# PHP project on Netbeans with Google API-PHP-CLIENT runs on XAMPP local environment but not on shared hosting

Tags: ssl, netbeans, composer-php, google-oauth, google-api-php-client

I am using Netbeans IDE to create a PHP project that authenticates with google-apis using a service account. The goal is to verify an in-app purchase via Google 'purchases-products' API. The service account is fully functional since I've used it to upload updates to another one of my apps in my Google Developer Console.

In the PHP project I use Composer to require the Google/Api-Client dependency from Packagist.
The project runs nicely on my local environment using XAMPP, and I do get a Google JSON format response stating that a purchase was made on my app with a given token ID.

The big problem I am facing is when I try to upload the project via FTP to my shared hosting website. Before, my domain used HTTP which I thought it was the problem. However, now my domain is set to HTTPS. So, it is more likely for Google to send the response to my shared hosting site.

NetBeans takes close to an hour in trying to upload the PHP files from the project via FTP. And, even then when I compare the files uploaded to the ones inside the NetBeans project some of them are missing, such as the Google/Auth folder. So, I try to upload that folder myself. But, nothing happens. When I load the https://mywebiste.org/index.php nothing shows up. No JSON response from Google such as the one I get when I run the project on my local XAMPP environment.

Here is how I try to authenticate using the Service Account inside the index.php file:

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';       
            
    echo "trying the shared hosting service call"."<br>";      
           

putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/vendor/pc-api-90898980932-543-8985erdc9923.json');
$client = new Google\Client();

$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
$client->setApplicationName('myapplicationname');
$client->addScope(Google\Service\AndroidPublisher::ANDROIDPUBLISHER);
echo "CLIENTCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC"."<br>";
echo var_dump($client)."<br>";
$service = new Google\Service\AndroidPublisher($client);
echo "SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS"."<br>";
echo var_dump($service)."<br>";
```

**I think that the PHP function putenv() is causing a problem, OR perhaps Google does not approve of the SSL certificate that my website is using**

I have been thinking of using Node.js inside a Firebase cloud function call and I am almost certain that there won't be any SSL problems or HTTPS issues. But, I want to authenticate via this PHP project using my website.

Any suggestions

Comment: "nothing shows up" - what have you tried to resolve that? Is there any error message given, maybe in your server's error log file? How is this problem related to SSL, Netbeans, Composer, or Google's libraries?

Comment: @NicoHaase Being a mobile programmer not a web developer I had a difficult time finding the right solution. But I did. See the answer I posted! Yes, those error logs were super helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I was able to get it to work. Seems like the FTP file transfer did not work completely.

1. First, I had to check the display PHP error option in my hosting account.
2. The errors were displayed and alerted me of the classes that were not found by the PHP client. This was very helpful!
3. I allowed the OAUTH PHP extension within the PHP configuration of my hosting account.
4. Then, I started uploading the missing files and folders from my Vendor folder from my other local PHP projects that worked on my XAMPP local environment.
5. ChatGPT was able to help me find the locations of this files and folders within the Vendor folder created by Composer.
6. As I suspected, the putenv() function was not reading the location of the JSON Service Account credentials file. So, I had to write the path of the JSON Service Account file in terms of the Vendor folder file structure hosted in my public_html folder. I was able to figure out how to write the location based on the display error messages that I got from the browser after loading the file.

**if you need help! just send me a message!**